# Ruby: file output blank

Tags: ruby, file-io, module

So I'm trying to build a program which tells me how many days are left till someone's birthday. I have a text file that I'm drawing data from. The problem is the **save method** is not working for some reason, and nothing is being printed to the output file. Thank you so much in advance!

```
require 'date'

Person = Struct.new(:name, :bday)

module Family

  Member = Hash.new

    File.readlines("bday_info.txt").each do |line|
      name, bday = line.split(',')
      person = Person.new(name, bday)
      Member[name] = bday
    end

    def self.next_bday(name)
      birthday = Date.parse(Family::Member[name])
      this_year = Date.new(Date.today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
      next_year = Date.new(Date.today.year + 1, birthday.month, birthday.day)
      if this_year > Date.today
        puts "\n#{(this_year - Date.today).to_i} days to #{name}'s birthday"
      else
        puts "\n#{(next_year - Date.today).to_i} days to #{name}'s birthday"
      end
    end

    def self.save(name)
      File.open("days_left.txt", "w") do |file|
        file.puts "#{next_bday(name)}"
      end
    end

end

loop do
  puts "\nName:"
  response = gets.chomp.capitalize
  if response.downcase == "quit"
    break
  elsif Family::Member.has_key?("#{response}") == false
    puts "\nYou ain't on the list"
  else
  Family.next_bday(response)
  Family.save(response) #WHY IS THIS LINE NOT WORKING???
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Family.next_bday` does not return anything (to be more precise - it's returning `nil` that last `puts` returns), thus nothing is written to the file.

Other notes(not directly related):

1. No reason in calling `Family.next_bday(response)` twice, just save return value from the first call
2. `Family::Member` constant looks more like a variable, more clean design will be to make the whole thing a class that takes input file name, reads data in initializer and then stores into a instance variable